# Getting Field data values of Specific document Name in Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new to Firestore database CRUD operations. I am using Flutter where I am able to retrieve document field data values from the auto generated document id's into a Listtile with ListView .

The issue is when I create a new document with my own name for the collection . I am not sure how to retrieve it .

So for this particular case . I have a collection named 'Liebenberg Primary School ' . I then created a Document-ID named ' contact' with 'tel' as field data . So I now want to retrieve the 'tel' field data value ('1234567') also into my Listtile

Below my code for retrieving field data for the auto-generated document id's .

```
 final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

 body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: db.collection('Liebenberg Primary School').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Center(
          child: LinearProgressIndicator(),
        );
      } else
        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
            return Card(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => DetailPage(
                        post: doc,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(doc['title']),
                  subtitle: Text(doc['content']),
                  trailing: Text(
                    timeago.format(
                      doc['created'].toDate(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
    },
  ),
```

[image: Field data for named document]

[image: Auto ID]

Comment: try doc['content']['tel']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the ref while fetching the snapshot like this

```
stream: db.collection('Liebenberg Primary School').document('contact').snapshots()
```